# why it doesnt display Date and time picker in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker

I am creating an MVC project, I am very new to it. I have Create View which has a datetime propery.

In Html, it just displays a simple textbox for datetime property. How can I make it Date and Time picker? And, here is my HTML code below...

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 datetimepicker">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my model class is like below

```
public partial class AntsoftCrmProjectTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int MinutesSpent { get; set; }
    public string ProblemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool ProblemIsFixed { get; set; }
    public string ProblemResult { get; set; }
    public string CurrentlyInCharge { get; set; }
    public int SupportId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show us your model class?

Comment: By the way, I dont want a fancy picker, basic will do the job for me

Comment: What browser are you using to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some type of HTML control for that.

```
<input type="date"'
```

has support in some browsers but it is limited depending on your browser and version and is only supported in HTML5.

Your best solution is to find something like the [jquery date and time picker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/). Use that and add some script to allow the user to pick the date time.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Html.EditorFor` will create a `html` `<textbox />` tag when run.

What you have to do is use a javascript library to convert that `EditorFor` into a `DateTimePicker` (you could use the `JQueryUI` - more details and a working example on msdn, [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4)), something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This should be the element generated by your EditorFor()  
        $('#CreatedTime').datepicker();
    })
</script>
```