# ASP.NET MVC built in date/time picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does asp.net mvc have a simple calendar/datepicker?
And i dont want to download any new scripts or plugins, like it has to be built in, Like bootstrap is default, when you start a project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it does not. try using telerik or jquery :)

Comment: Bootstrap is not "built in", it is downloaded through nuget like many other MVC components, including MVC itself.

Comment: Is there a guide to a newbie to use JqueryUI datepicker, step by step in VS 2015 - asp.net mvc (i have looked, but what i found was not noob friendly)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [why it doesnt display Date and time picker in MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35554285/1260204)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a "date" [input type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp). Browsers which support it (e.g. Chrome) will display a datepicker.

```
    <input type="date" name="anyname">
```

MVC was deliberately written without ASP-style user controls. Microsoft wanted to shift the development burden from themselves onto the community (many of whom are willing to work for nothing).

So unfortunately you will need to use software libraries (scripts, plugins etc.) when using MVC.

For better support across browsers, try [jQueryUI datepickers](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Will firefox display a datepicker?

Comment: Just tried it myself (a good way of finding things out). No, Firefox doesn't.